# Cómo configurar Windows para que los puertos USB se abran y cierren a determinadas horas

Tags: windows10, configuración, usb

Pregunté previamente a ChatGPT3 si había alguna manera de poder configurar un pc para que abra sus puertos USB a unas horas específicas, porque debo irme de viaje y debo dejar siempre un móvil conectado a uno de los puertos USB. Y no quiero que el teléfono "reviente" porque tengo que usarlo a distancia, de forma remota.

Entonces ChatGPT3 me ofreció dos códigos para usarlos como "batch", y que programase su activación en Configuración de Tareas de Windows. El problema: es que los "batch" que me ofreció ChatGPT3 no funcionan... uno era para cerrar puertos USB, y el otro para abrirlos luego de cerrarlos...

reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR /v Start /t REG_DWORD /d 3 /f

El código anterior es el que ChatGPT3 me ofrece para abrir puertos USB una vez que están cerrados.

El código siguiente es el que me ofrece ChatGPT para CERRAR puertos USB:

reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR /v Start /t REG_DWORD /d 4 /f

Como formulo en mi consulta, he intentado ejecutar ambos códigos como Administrador, pero no entiendo dónde está el fallo. Ninguno de los dos me funciona.

Los ejecuto como Administrador por separado, pero nada, tampoco funcionan. Mi cuenta de Windows tiene permisos de Administrador, me he asegurado de mirarlo bien.

Al preguntarle a ChatGPT3 el porqué los códigos que me ofreció no estaban funcionando, su respuesta fue: "debe pedir asistencia técnica en este caso". Vaya, que ChatGPT3 me generó unos códigos que no es capaz de corregirlos (asumo que el problema es la solución ofrecida por ChatGPT3).

Necesito tener conectado al puerto USB de uno de mis ordenadores un teléfono móvil con una aplicación llamada "airdroid" para poder acceder al teléfono de forma remota. Y desde esta aplicación, usar la app "Wolon" para poder despertar del modo suspensión a mis ordenadores y poder trabajar a distancia.., imprescindible hacer esto ya que mi empresa no me permite realizar mi trabajo desde fuera de mi país de residencia.

He buscado y buscado en Google, desde aplicaciones hasta cerrar puertos USB de manera convencional (administrador de sistemas) pero el móvil simplemente sigue cargándose aunque deshabilite los puertos USB.

Gracias por leer, y espero de veras que alguien pueda echarme una mano en este problema.

Comment: Hola, ese es el problema de usar ChatGPT ... o cualquier otra IA para generar codigo que no entiendes o no conoces ...

Comment: Ante todo, traer dudas Generadas por ChatGPT no es un Topic del sitio... asique tu pregunta queda fuera de sitio.

Comment: por otro lado, lo interesante es si estas interesado en aprender a programar, deberias estudiar el codigo que te dio ChatGPT, que el mismo te explique que hace cada linea ... eso lo hace muy bien.... como herramienta autodidacta.

Comment: una vez que entiendas que hace el codigo, podrias investigar que error tiene, y por que no funciona... a lo mejor puede ver algun mensaje por pantalla al ejecutar el batch o aprendes a debugear el codigo batch ... etc

Comment: otro motivo por el cual no podemos ayudarte... es que no has compartido el codigo... sea tuyo o de ChatGPT no somos adivinos, ni creamos sofware para otros usuarios... simplemente ayudamos a comprender y corregir codigo...

Comment: una solucion o alternativa... puede ser buscar un software que haga lo que quieres... asi te conectas remotamente y con el software contralas los puertos usb .... valida que remotamente te funcione antes de hirte de viaje y que la licencia por lo menos dure hasta que regrese o sea gratuito...

Comment: Hola, sobre generar código "no entiendo no conozco". En esto tiene s toda la razón.

Comment: Respecto a "estudiar el código" . Me voy en pocos días de viaje... me declaro incapaz de resolver el problema por mí mismo, por tal motivo recuerro a un lugar especializado como éste para tener quién poder hechar una mano...

Comment: El código está Lo he comparitdo,. Son dos.

Comment: He buscado de todo, apps, programas,,, no he encontrado. he usado algún que otro software pare  cerrar puertos peron nada... aunque los cierre, el móvil sigue cargando mediante USB.,

Comment: Hay una herramienta llamada [devcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon) que te puede servir. [Aquí hay un ejemplo](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon-examples#example-30-disable-devices-by-an-id-pattern). En mí caso tengo Visual Studio instalado y no cuento con la herramienta, pero sí con [pnputil](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/pnputil), una alternativa más moderna.

Comment: Puedo acceder a pnputil desde la consola de desarrollador de Visual Studio. El comando sería `pnputil /disable-device id`. Deberías encontrar el ID del puerto USB.

Comment: @Mateo entiendo que quieras ayudarle, pero el quiere que le den una solucion hecha ya lista y funcionando por que se va de viaje ... y no quiere pasar por la curva de aprendizaje que requiere lo que intenta hacer... de mi parte creo que su planteamiento esta mal hecho... ya que asi no es como funciona el sitio.

Comment: Elimine tu pregunta anterior, porque es basicamente lo mismo. Entiendes mal como funciona este sitio. Aca ayudamos a resolver problemas concretos. lo tuyo, mas alla que aca no compartiste el codigo, es un problema para el cual buscas la solucion erronea. Como viste, no queres cerrar un puerto. Queres deshabilitarlo por hardware para que deje de tirar corriente, cosa que me parece es muy dificil, y mas por soft... el puerto esta hecho justamente para tirar corriente todo el tiempo.

Comment: Ahora, te explicaron que dejar el celular cargando no generaba problemas con la bateria del celular. Eso estaba en la otra pregunta. Ahora, por favor, edita esta pregunta, explica el motivo por el cual es un problema que el celu este conectado todo el tiempo (y si usas bluetooth?) y pone el codigo que no entendiste y segun vos no sirve aca.

Comment: *el móvil simplemente sigue cargándose aunque deshabilite los puertos USB* Una solución es cortar el pin de alimentación V+ en el conector, con lo que nunca recibirá energía del PC.

Comment: @CandidMoe el no quiere cortar la corriente, entiendo que quiere controlar el flujo de corriente ... para que el celu no se le inche la bateria... obviamente esto no en todas las gamas y marcas de celu esta controlado... pero en si ... esta mal planteada la pregunta, usa ChatGPT ... por que esta cuenta no esta baneada ... como todas las otras ...

Comment: @Francisco él no quiere controlar la corriente, quiere poder poner a cargar o dejar de cargar su teléfono. [Candid Moe tiene razón](https://superuser.com/a/1642876). Debería pensar en armar algo con un microcontrolador. Tal vez usando un relé.

Comment: Yo es que estoy mayor e igual no entendí algo o me perdí o algo pero ... ¿¿ porqué no dejas el portatil encendido con `teamviewer` en ejecución y listo ?? Mi portatil del curro se pega meses encendido, y no recuerdo que haya *explotado* todavía ... y, a unas malas, un enchufe temporizado y a correr.

Comment: @Mateo sobre la solución que planteas con devcon la voy a estudiar. Te agradezco de veras

Comment: @gbianchi la idea es que no siempre esté cerrado el puerto USB. Sino que solo pudiese abrirse a conveniencia, por ejemplo mientras accedo al pc de forma remota, para en ese instante poder cargarse el móvil, Como voy a estar trabajando diario, es algo que deberé hacer bastante a menudo. Y el modelo que uso tampoco dispone  en sus opciones la de carga inhalámbrica

Comment: @gbianchi porque entiendo puede aumentar el riesgo de sobrecalentamiento (dejar el móvil permanentemente cargando) y en la web de Huawei dice que no evita que en algún momento la batería reanude su carga hasta su máxima capacidad. Respecto  a os 2 códigos están incluídos en la pregunta. Tanto el de abrir como el de cerrar puertos (los que me dio la IA pero no me funciona)

Comment: @Trauma  porque es que en mi caso no planeo quedarme meses sinó más bien años "fuera de casa".. (así que mi casa ya no sería "mi casa")... no sé yo qué tan factible sea eso de dejar "años" un pc conectado las 24/7 los 365... y bueno lo otro que me imagino ya sabes es que en España el precio dela luz anda por las nubes ...

Comment: @Trauma lo había pensado lo del enchufe temporizador... el problema es que por la naturaleza de mi trabajo... nunca sé cuándo voy a tener trabajo disponible (debo estar casi cada 30 min revisando y no deseo que el enchufe me apague el pc si estoy en pleno trabajo) por eso mi idea era más bien programar la carga del móvil ya que estará siempre conectado al PC (y hasta ahora no e encontrado la solución)

Comment: creo que no es la solucion correcta cuando hablamos de años ... pro que debe ser una pc en la casa ... y no un servicio de escritorio remoto...